# Read outline color of rectangle/texbox

Tags: python, python-pptx

I am trying to read the outline color of a rectangle and I get the following error

AttributeError: no .rgb property on color type '_NoneColor'

I am using the same code with different slide and the results are coming out as expected. I am sure that there is something incorrect with the shape however, I am not able to exactly identify the issue... Can someone help?

for shape in slide_3.shapes:

```
if shape.name[:9] == 'Rectangle':

    shape_color = shape.fill.fore_color.rgb
    line_color = shape.line.color.rgb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of possible combinations for color-types and fill-types. You need to start at the beginning and navigate your way through, interrogating the types as you go.

```
from pptx.enum.dml import MSO_COLOR_TYPE, MSO_FILL

def read_outline_color(shape):
    line_fill = shape.line.fill
    print("fill-type == %s" % line_fill.type)
    # ---we only handle solid, which is most common
    # ---the other common value is "background" which means no-fill
    if line_fill.type != MSO_FILL.SOLID:
        return

    # ---color can be specified as specific RGB color or a theme color
    # ---like ACCENT_1
    line_color = line_fill.fore_color
    print("color-type == %s" % line_color.type)
    if line_color.type == MSO_COLOR_TYPE.SCHEME:
        print("color == %s" % line_color.theme_color
    elif line_color.type == MSO_COLOR_TYPE.RGB:
        print("color == %s" % line_color.rgb
    else:
        print("No line color")
```

Comment: Hi Steve - Can we print the MSO_COLOR_TYPE.SCHEME or MSO_FILL.SOLID values in RGB? When I try to print I get only Solid(1) and I would like to know the RGB value for this solid (1). Is this possible???

Comment: `MSO_FILL.SOLID` is a _fill type_, not a color (other types are pattern, bitmap, etc.). So no, you can't find a color of "solid" because there is none. `SCHEME` colors (aka. "theme" colors) are set by the presentation theme. There is no API support yet for interrogating theme colors.

Comment: Thank you, Steve. Let me try and take a different approach to achieve this.